# How to get a all Eloquent Models in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, reflection, laravel-5.5

I am hoping to find a way to get a list of all Eloquent models in my app. Perhaps I need to use reflection.

Here is what I tried to do. However, this does not work because `get_declared_classes()`

1. returns an array of strings not objects.
2. does not show the model classes.

.

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class IdentifierGeneratorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class) {
            if (!($class instanceof Model)) {
                continue;
            }
            // At this point I know that $class is an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
            // I should be able to call any method of the Model object
            // like this $class->getIncrementing(); 
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of variable variables/variadics.

```
foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class) {
    $c = new $class;
    if ($c instanceof Model) {
        // it is a model
        $c->getIncrementing();
    }
}
```

Note that you can use a try catch for the object instantiation to catch errors.

Comment: only gets instantiated classes.